# vim puts extra space for every accented character

Tags: vim

Whenever I type an accented character in vim, like for example: `é` it places an extra space like so `é<space>`.

Small gif animation that illustrates the problem: [Link here](http://g.recordit.co/ds3dkYtRIG.gif). Notice that in the screen recording I am at no point pressing the space bar and yet they appear.

It's the exact same problem as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965050/vim-extra-space-inserted-after-accented-letters-or-%C3%B1) and in [Super user question](https://superuser.com/questions/848667/vim-inserting-white-spaces-after-accentuations-and-other-special-characters-on-m) too, but the solution proposed for both - `set encoding=utf-8` - is not working for me. I've placed that in both the `.vimrc` and in a running session and none worked.

In MacVim, which `set encoding?` also outputs `encoding=utf-8`, this issue doesn't happen.

I installed vim with `brew`, here's the `info` command of it:

```
vim: stable 7.4.488, HEAD
http://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with: ex-vi
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488 (1600 files, 26M) *
  Built from source with: --override-system-vi
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: lua ✔, luajit ✔
==> Options
--disable-nls
    Build vim without National Language Support (translated messages, keymaps)
--override-system-vi
    Override system vi
--with-client-server
    Enable client/server mode
--with-lua
    Build vim with lua support
--with-luajit
    Build with luajit support
--with-mzscheme
    Build vim with mzscheme support
--with-python3
    Build vim with python3 instead of python[2] support
--with-tcl
    Build vim with tcl support
--without-perl
    Build vim without perl support
--without-python
    Build vim without python support
--without-ruby
    Build vim without ruby support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

And `:version` info here:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  5 2015 21:44:59)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-258
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cmdline_info    +emacs_tags      -gettext         +lua             +mouse_urxvt     +profile         +statusline      +transparency    -X11
+arabic          +comments        +eval            -hangul_input    +menu            +mouse_xterm     +python          -sun_workshop    +user_commands   -xfontset
+autocmd         +conceal         +ex_extra        +iconv           +mksession       +multi_byte      -python3         +syntax          +vertsplit       +xim
+balloon_eval    +cryptv          +extra_search    +insert_expand   +modify_fname    +multi_lang      +quickfix        +tag_binary      +virtualedit     -xsmp
+browse          +cscope          +farsi           +jumplist        +mouse           -mzscheme        +reltime         +tag_old_static  +visual          -xterm_clipboard
++builtin_terms  +cursorbind      +file_in_path    +keymap          +mouseshape      +netbeans_intg   +rightleft       -tag_any_white   +visualextra     -xterm_save
+byte_offset     +cursorshape     +find_in_path    +langmap         +mouse_dec       +odbeditor       +ruby            +tcl             +viminfo         -xpm
+cindent         +dialog_con_gui  +float           +libcall         -mouse_gpm       +path_extra      +scrollbind      +terminfo        +vreplace
+clientserver    +diff            +folding         +linebreak       -mouse_jsbterm   +perl            +signs           +termresponse    +wildignore
+clipboard       +digraphs        -footer          +lispindent      +mouse_netterm   +persistent_undo +smartindent     +textobjects     +wildmenu
+cmdline_compl   +dnd             +fork()          +listcmds        +mouse_sgr       +postscript      -sniff           +title           +windows
+cmdline_hist    -ebcdic          +fullscreen      +localmap        -mouse_sysmouse  +printer         +startuptime     +toolbar         +writebackup
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Ve
rsions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/inclu
de -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D
_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -framework Core
Foundation -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa  -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000 -L/usr/local/lib -llu
ajit-5.1 -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl -frame
work CoreFoundation -framework Ruby
```

And my locale:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You know you can run MacVim *in* your shell with `$ mvim -v`, right?

Comment: @romainl hm.. I've tried that and still have the same issue. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: does this also happen with new files created on your local filesystem? I made the experience, that files from other sources (like windows) can cause troubles for vim, despite the fact that encoding is set. because vim tries to write in utf-8 encoding to a file which originally is latin-1. if this is the fact, try to convert the file with `iconv -f latin-1 -t utf-8`

Comment: @syss thanks for your replied. I double checked that and no, that is not the case. For files created in my filsystem and inside vim even the issue still occurs. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post `:version`?

Comment: @svlasov updated answer with that

Comment: What's the locale in your terminal?

Comment: I have it set all to `en_US.UTF-8` normally. I've tried with `pt_PT.UTF-8` but the same thing happens.

Comment: en_US.UTF-8 seem to be fine. Can you check the output of `$ echo $TERM` ? Also check the contents of your _~/.inputrc_ .

Comment: Check also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4606636/1046584

Comment: What exactly are you typing to insert the `é`? I've tried to insert it using (not on Mac but Linux admittedly) by typing `Ctrl-shift-u 00e9 <Space>` and I don't have the same problem

Comment: Can you post your vimrc?

Comment: Are you using `terminal.app`? Have you tried mucking about with its locale/encoding settings? Trying a different terminal might be worthwhile too. Do accented characters display properly on the shell prompt?

Comment: (Moving "answer" to comment.) This is a stretch, but you could check whether your accented characters are inserted using combining characters too, in case that's tripping something up. One easy way would be to `:set delcombine` and see if you can delete the accent separately.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you had only run `:set encoding?` in GUI MacVim. What does it say in terminal Vim/MacVim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the suggestions of the comments worked for me, so I kept on digging on the issue myself. In the end it was just a matter of unchecking an iTerm setting.

[image: iterm settings]